# How to loop through an array on the click of a button?

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I want to loop through the list `artists` and each time the button is pressed, I want the next artist to be added in the `<p>` tag.

```js
let para = document.querySelector('p');

const artists = ['Atif Aslam', 'Nusrat Fateh Ali Khan', 'Kendrick Lamar', 'Travis Scot', 'JCole', 'Sidhu', 'Ataullah EsaKheilvi'];
let info = 'One of my top favorite artist is '


function myArt() {
  for (i = 0; i < artists.length; i++) {
    para.textContent = info + artists[i];
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <button id="myArtists" onclick="myArt()"> Click To Find Out!</button>
  <p> </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Well, your logic is starting at index zero every time.  So that's a problem.  And it's always going to finish by setting the last artist as the value.  So that's also a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop for what you're trying to do. Instead, you want to keep track of an index for the artist and increment the index every time `myArt()` is called.

```js
let para = document.querySelector('p');

const artists = ['Atif Aslam', 'Nusrat Fateh Ali Khan', 'Kendrick Lamar', 'Travis Scot', 'JCole', 'Sidhu', 'Ataullah EsaKheilvi'];

const info = 'One of my top favorite artist is ';

let artistIndex = 0;

function myArt() {
  if(artistIndex < artists.length) {
    para.innerText = info + artists[artistIndex];
    artistIndex++;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="myArtists" onclick="myArt()"> Click To Find Out!</button>
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not looping, it is that you do not want a loop. You just need a variable as a pointer to go through your array as such.

```
  let para = document.querySelector('p');

  const artists = ['Atif Aslam', 'Nusrat Fateh Ali Khan', 'Kendrick Lamar', 'Travis Scot', 'JCole', 'Sidhu', 'Ataullah EsaKheilvi'];
  let info = 'One of my top favorite artist is '

  //Array pointer
  let counter = 0;
  function myArt() {
    para.textContent = info + artists[counter++];
    if (counter == artists.length) {
      //Rest pointer
      counter = 0
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to loop through it if you just keep track of the index. You could use a global variable or code it as an attribute like this:

```js
const artists = ['Atif Aslam', 'Nusrat Fateh Ali Khan', 'Kendrick Lamar', 'Travis Scot', 'JCole', 'Sidhu', 'Ataullah EsaKheilvi'];
let info = 'One of my top favorite artist is '

const setup = () => {

  const myArtists = document.querySelector('#myArtists');
  myArtists.addEventListener('click', myArt);

};

const myArt = (event) => {
  const button = event.target;
  
  const previousIndex = button.hasAttribute('currentIndex') ? parseInt(button.getAttribute('currentIndex'),10) : -1;
  
  const currentIndex = previousIndex >= artists.length - 1 ? 0 : previousIndex + 1;
  
  button.setAttribute('currentIndex', currentIndex);
  
  let para = document.querySelector('p');
  para.textContent = info + artists[currentIndex];
}

window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

```html
<button id="myArtists"> Click To Find Out!</button>
<p> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop. Just use a global variable for the current index pointer.

A simple way to have this working, plus for a circular 'looping' when clicking on the button.
You could use module `index % artists.length` which will mirror the index:

```js
const $p = document.querySelector('p');
const textPrefix = 'One of my top favorite artist is: ';
const artists = ['Atif Aslam', 'Nusrat Fateh Ali Khan', 'Kendrick Lamar', 'Travis Scot', 'JCole', 'Sidhu', 'Ataullah EsaKheilvi'];
let currentArtistIndex = 0;

function nextArtist() {
  $p.innerText = `${textPrefix}${artists[currentArtistIndex++ % artists.length]}`; 
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="myArtists" onclick="nextArtist()"> Click To Find Out The Next Artist!</button>
  <p> </p>
</body>
```